# if i create a new object and put it in the main method, is java going to run the constructor or the entire class?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a `class` called Panel

```
 public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
       public Board(){
            setFocusable(true);
            setBackground(Color.black)
            setDoubleBuffered(true);
            timer= new Timer(16,this);
            timer.start();
       }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            //.........some codes here...//

       }
       public void render(Graphics2D g){
            //....some code here....//
       }
}
```

and I run it in the main `class`.

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
public Main(){
    add(new Panel());
    //....some code....//
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    new Main();
}
}
```

since `actionPerformed()` and `render()` methods are not in the constructor.

Comment: Try it and see what happens. Add a System.out.println(...) statement in each of the methods to see when they execute.

Comment: my question is that render and actionPerformed are not in the constructor, how are they being executed? it is because of Timer?

Comment: And that is what you should have originally stated in the question so we don't have to guess what you are thinking about. Anyway your question has been answered. So its time to accept an answer.

Comment: sorry i had to pull an example out of my butt. and i did put
actionPerformed() and render() methods are not in the constructor.
so read before speak.

Comment: You asked "what will happen". The implication is that you did not know what would happen. Read the answers. Nobody understood your real question until you clarified that the `actionPerformed` method was invoked. Then people looked closer at you code to explain the usage of the Timer.

Comment: yeah, sorry. gotta admit my question is deviant.. and your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new object, only the constructor (and any methods it calls) will execute. In general, methods run only when called, either by your code or by the framework (typically in response to events—in your case, the event is the elapse of the `Timer` delay time).

Note that you had a typo in the code you originally posted:

```
public void actionPerfomred(ActionEvent e){
```

should be

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
```

If you annotate overridden methods with `@Override`, the compiler will catch errors like this for you. That way you won't have to figure out at run time why your method wasn't called.

Comment: The thing about programming is you need to think logically. So does it make sense that all the methods would automatically execute when a class is constructed? Spoon feeding doesn't help the OP to think for themselves. Learning some basic problem solving skills is something every programmer needs to learn.

Comment: but actionPerformed method is called without being written in the constructor.

Comment: @camickr - It does help to explain the basic rules of the road. Thinking logically only works if you have some facts to work with.

Comment: @Bango - `actionPerformed` is called by the framework when an event (like a mouse click) occurs. Absent an action, the method won't be called.

Comment: That is why you do a simple test. Then if you don't understand the results you state your results and ask why it happened that way.

Comment: @camickr - from the comments, it's clear that OP already noticed that `actionPerformed` was being called without his code calling it. The entire question, I think, was motivated by that observation. Telling OP to observe some more isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - so you saying Timer starts the actionPerformed?

Comment: @Bango - In this case, it appears so. The documentation for `Timer` says that is what should happen.

Comment: Exactly, my point. This information is only available in the comments. Your initial answer has nothing to do with the Timer because the information wasn't available when you answered. This information should have been made available in the initial question.

Comment: @Bango - Note that the first argument to the `Timer` constructor is the delay time in _milliseconds_. Sixteen milliseconds is going to seem like no delay at all to human perception.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - oh okay, thank you sir. so after every 16ms delay the actionPerformed and render are executed right?

Comment: @Bango - The `actionPerformed` method alone is called by the timer. The `render` method is not automatically called then. However, the code in `actionPerformed` may trigger a call to `render` by the framework (if, for instance, you call `repaint()`) or it may call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

It will obviously call constructor only. If you don't have any constructor then compiler will call default empty constructor. But when you create an object only and only constructor is called.

Answer (score 0):

Java will only run the constructor. Also i noticed that the constructor name of Panel class doesn't match with its constructor. It has to be same name.
Instead of this

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
       public Board(){
            setFocusable(true);
            setBackground(Color.black)
            setDoubleBuffered(true);
            timer= new Timer(16,this);
            timer.start();
       }

}
```

you do

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
   public Panel(){
        setFocusable(true);
        setBackground(Color.black)
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        timer= new Timer(16,this);
        timer.start();
   }
}
```

Also with regards to `actionPerformed`  event methods, you have to manually wire them with the button/list on which you have to do some action.

Answer (score 0):

> but actionPerformed method is called without being written in the constructor.

Now that is a better question. That is the behaviour you should have stated when you first asked the question so we don't guess why you are asking the question.

That is because you are using a `Timer`. When the Timer fires the `ActionListener` added to the Timer is invoked. Your class implements the ActionListener so the `actionPerformed()` method of you class is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It will call the constructor only .

> is java going to run the constructor or the entire class?

No . Its not going to run the entire class .

Also while the class is loading it will run the stuffs inside the static block  , if any are present .

Answer (score 0):

```
if i create a new object and put it in the main method, is java going to run
the constructor or the entire class?
```

First of all what do you mean by java going to run. When ever you call `javac` with the class names Eg `javac *.java` all of your java files will be compiled to an intermediate byte code. Now when you call `java Main` java interpreter will start interpreting your byte code starting from `public static void main(String args[])` function. Java is just a name of programming language you can say is `jvm going to execute the constructor or the entire class?`

Secondly what do you mean by executing the entire class. There are two aspects in this

1. `Creating new object` : Whenever you create a new object (by using the keyword new) corresponding constructor is invoked and the object is created. As the constructor is executed if there are any methods that you are calling from the constructor then they will get executed as well.
2. `Calling function/methods` : If your methods are not private then you can call these methods after creating their object(depending on the access modifier used).

Your case

```
new Panel();
```

New Panel object is created(corresponding constructor is invoked).No other method will be executed on it's own.

```
my question is that render and actionPerformed are not in the constructor,
how are they being executed? it is because of Timer?
```

This is the question you should not be asking. You are the programmer and you must have written the code for your requirement. As for the use case I can tell you this

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //.........some codes here...//

   }
```

you can create a JButton or for that matter any Component and add an ActionListner to it. An ActionListner has this method. Since you class Panel implements ActionListner you are implementing the function actionPerformed(). Eg.

```
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.addActionListener(new Panel());
```

Answer (score 0):

`actionPerformed` will call by timer trigger.

`render` method will not called. If you want paint something in swing `JPanel`, should overwrite `paint(Graphics g)` method defined in `JComponent`.

take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html